# Flutter || Listview builder taking whole space in flutter web when using on autocomplete widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, expandablelistview, flutter-listview

I am working on a autocomplete widget where the user will type something and it will suggest the registered names.I am fetching the data from the JSON api.
I have used autocomplete widget in which I have used listview builder but it is taking the whole space
example is in the video:-[image]
my autocomplete widget code :-

```
SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 350,
                        child: Autocomplete<Data>(
                            optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue value) {
                              if (value.text.isEmpty) {
                                return List.empty();
                              }
                              return userModel!.data!
                                  .where((element) => element.firstName!
                                      .toLowerCase()
                                      .contains(value.text.toLowerCase()))
                                  .toList();
                            },
                            displayStringForOption: (Data d) =>
                                '${d.firstName!} ${d.lastName}',
                            onSelected: (value) => print(value.firstName),
                            fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                    TextEditingController controller,
                                    FocusNode node,
                                    Function onFieldSubmitted) =>
                                TextField(
                                  controller: controller,
                                  focusNode: node,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      filled: true,
                                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      hintText: 'Enter company Name',
                                      hintStyle: t3O40),
                                ),
                            optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                    Function onSelected,
                                    Iterable<Data> dataList) =>
                                Material(
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: dataList.length,
                                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                                          Data d =
                                              dataList.elementAt(index);
                                          return InkWell(
                                            onTap: () => onSelected(d),
                                            child:
                                                Builder(builder: (context) {
                                              return ListTile(
                                                title: Text(d.firstName!),
                                                leading: Image.network(
                                                  d.avatar!,
                                                  height: 40,
                                                  width: 40,
                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }),
                                          );
                                        })),
                                  ),
                                )),
```

),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap Material widget with Align widget and include Alignment.topLeft
This happens because material widgets take a lot of space and then in Sizedbox you have to include your specific width
like this: -

```
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Material(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 250,
                                     child:ListView.builder() ....
```